# Move arrow function to another exported function

Tags: node.js, arrow-functions

I have a problem. I want to clean my code and put function to another file but I always get an error:

```
getMe is not a function
```

why? I want to use it in already exported function getExchangeRateIntent. Is that causing a problem?

**outside.js**

```
const getRate = (base) => {
  console.log('My base currency is '+base);
};

module.exports = {getRate};
```

**getRate.js**

```
const getMe = ('./outside.js');

module.exports = {

  'getExchangeRateIntent': (conv, parameter) => {
    const currencyBase = (parameter['currencyBase']);
    const currencyTarget = (parameter['currencyTarget']);
    const amount = (parameter['amount']);
    console.log(currencyBase);
    console.log(currencyTarget);
    console.log(amount);

    getMe('USD');

    conv.ask('nothing');
  },
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.exports = {getRate};` you are exporting an object. With your import:

`const getMe = ('./outside.js');`

you are importing an object. So this is not a function. This is not a proper import also.

For proper import you could write something like this:

`import {getRate} from './outside.js`;

And use it like this:

`getRate('USD');`

Or if you want to use require:

`const getMe = require('./outside.js');`

And then you can call function like this in second case:

`getMe.getRate('USD')`